# Angular Material Table header on scrolling up overlaps the box shadow of the main heading

Tags: html, css, angular

when i scroll up the page the Table header overlaps on to the shadow of the main header as shown in the below screenshot :

[Page when it isn't scrolled up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3229.png)

[Page when it's scrolled up it overlaps the shadow on the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXB3H.png)

Please find below HTML code for the Angular Mat table:

```
   <ng-container>
<h1 id="opportunity-header" style="margin-left: 7.5%; margin-top: 22px;">
  Opportunities - {{ accountName }}
</h1>
 <div class="opportunity-container">
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="opportunityList">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
     <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header>
      No.
      </th>
      <td *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" mat-cell>
        {{ i + 1 }}
     </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell class="nameColumn">
      Name
    </th>
     <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell class="name">
         {{ element.getName() }}
     </td>
   </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="isAssociated">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell class="isAssociatedColumn">
      isAssociated ({{ opportunityAssociated() }})
    </th>
    <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell class="isAssociated">
      {{ element.getIsAssociated() ? "Yes" : "No" }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="stage">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell class="stageColumn">
      Stage
    </th>
    <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell class="stage">
      {{ element.getStage() }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell class="amountColumn">
      Amount
    </th>
    <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell class="amount">$ {{ element.getAmount() }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true" mat-header-row></tr>
  <tr *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" mat-row></tr>
  </table>
    <div *ngIf="opportunities?.length == 0" class="empty-record">
      No Opportunities
     <mat-divider class="empty-divider"></mat-divider>
    </div>
   </div>
  </ng-container>
```

CSS code:

```
        .opportunity-container {
           height: 251px;
           margin-left: 7.5%;
           margin-bottom: 35px;
           overflow: auto;
           }

       .table {
          width: 100%;
          }

      .empty-record{
       padding-top: 62px;
       padding-bottom: 27px;
       text-align: center;
       }

      .empty-divider{
       margin-top: 55px;
      }

      .empty{
       margin-left: 64px;
      }

      .table{
      padding-top: 25px;
      }

       th.mat-header-cell, td.mat-cell, td.mat-footer-cell{
       text-align: center;
       width: 229px;
       }

       ::-webkit-scrollbar {
       width: 5px;
       }

     ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 10px;
        }

     ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: var(--gray-600);
        border-radius: 10px;
       }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: var(--gray-700);
     }

     :host {
    margin: 1.3em 0 0;
   }
```

While scrolling up the page the mat table overlaps my main header bar(in yellow) , which also overlaps the shadow of the main header as seen in the second image inside the red box.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try setting `z-index` of header?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work- z-index: 1

Comment: try `z-index:99999`

Comment: have you tried sticky header?If its possible give us a stackblitz.

Comment: `<tr *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true" mat-header-row></tr>` i have used sticky header that's the problem , without sticky header is working fine

Answer (score 1):

i used z-index:99999 on the mat-toolbar instead of z-index: 1 and it worked !!!!

Comment: Good to hear that my comment helped you :)